# Как работает пространство имен в h-файлах?

Tags: c++, g++

Осваиваю использование `h-файлов` и не могу понять, как использовать `пространство имен` для `заголовков`. Есть 3 файла:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "add.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace fr;

int main(){
    cout<<add(1,2);
}
```

add.cpp:

```
int add(int a, int b){return a+b;};
```

add.h:

```
namespace fr{
    int add(int a,int b);
}
```

Я понимаю, что скорее всего ошибка в `add.cpp`, но не понимаю как ее исправить
Ошибка такая:

```
 undefined reference to `fr::add(int, int)'
```

make-файл:

```
all:
    g++ -o main main.cpp add.cpp
```

Как можно использовать пространство имен?

Компилятор - `g++ mingw x32 7.3.0`
ОС - `Windows 10`

Comment: А в add.cpp определение функции поместить в пространство имен не пробовали?...

Comment: @Harry пытался, но я не знаю как

Comment: `namespace fr{ int add(int a, int b){return a+b;} }`

Comment: @user7860670 Спасибо, помогло

Comment: Не понимаю — объявление в пространство имен поместить сумели, а определение — нет? Или это не вы заголовочный файл писали?

Comment: @Harry, я делал по тутору без пространства имен, а его(namespace) сделать я сам догадался, вот и сделал по своему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно в add.cpp поместить определение функции в пространство имен:

```cpp
namespace fr{ int add(int a, int b){return a+b;} }
```